# How to Deactivate my Android phone using IMEI number?

Tags: lost-phone

I lost my Sony Xperia Sola(MT27i) recently.

As there was no SIM card inside the phone, when got lost, I am finding it very difficult to access my mobile online from mobilesecurity.norton.com, which I have installed on my device.

All that I have in control is the IMEI number of the gadget.

Can anyone help me suggest on how to lock or make my phone completely useless?

I got official confidential files stored in it.

Please help other than suggesting to go for filing FIR, approach network operator, all that stuff.

Comment: In short, you **need** to notify your mobile operator to block the IMEI and therefore prevent your handset getting registered on the said mobile operator's network, having said that, it would work outside of the country of origin regardless of network block or not *provided* it is unlocked. As for "official confidental files" stored on the handset is not exactly a suitable place to have it on the handset in the first place.